# Retrieve only one file per product by giving priority to Jpg over Doc

Tags: mysql, arrays

I have the following "image" table in place...

```
Id  Idu idA Doc_pic Doc_cont    Doc_name    Doc_type
1   1   1   yes     no          a.jpg       jpg
1   1   1   no      yes         b_doc.jpg   Doc
3   1   2   yes     no          c.jpg       Jpg
4   1   2   no      yes         D_doc.jpg   Doc
5   1   3   yes     no          e.jpg       Jpg
6   1   3   yes     no          f.jpg       Jpg
7   1   3   no      yes         G_doc.jpg   Doc
8   2   5   no      yes         F_doc.jpg   Doc
9   3   6   yes     no          h.jpg       Jpg
10  3   8   yes     no          j.jpg       Jpg
11  4   4   no      yes         K_doc.jpg   Doc
12  4   4   no      yes         L_doc.jpg   Doc
13  4   4   yes     no          m.jpg       Jpg
14  4   9   yes     no          n.jpg       Jpg
```

as you see I have three identifier, id, idu and ida

id - is the main id for the table image.
idu - is the user who has put the images.
ida - is the product id from the other table which have this images and documents linked to it.

how do I show for each product only Doc_type= jpg and only one, if not available like id=8 then show it the doc.

The output i want after the query should be...

```
1   1   1   yes no  a.jpg   jpg
3   1   2   yes no  c.jpg   Jpg
5   1   3   yes no  e.jpg   Jpg
8   2   5   no  yes F_doc.jpg   Doc
9   3   6   yes no  h.jpg   Jpg
10  3   8   yes no  j.jpg   Jpg
13  4   4   yes no  m.jpg   Jpg
14  4   9   yes no  n.jpg   Jpg
```

I have tried all possible ways in mysql select, distinct, group by and more clauses i have used but no luck some one help may be ...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You wanted to include in your table output a `Doc_type` of `Doc` only once? How do you want it to trigger?

Comment: Isn't `Id` column unique ? I see two `1` 's !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of achieving it :

```
SELECT
    image.*
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT idA FROM image ) idA_list

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Id ,idA
            FROM
                image
            WHERE
                Doc_type = 'jpg'
            GROUP BY idA
        )
        jpg_images ON jpg_images.idA = idA_list.idA

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                Id ,idA
            FROM
                image
            WHERE
                Doc_type = 'doc'
            GROUP BY idA
        )
        doc_images ON doc_images.idA = idA_list.idA

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        image ON image.id = COALESCE( jpg_images.id ,doc_images.id )
```

Comment: did you intend to leave 2 answers to the same question?

Comment: Thanks that was the answer.

Comment: Both my answers do the job but one might be faster . Unless you try both on large tables it probably would be hard to find which one could be faster . Considering one less `JOIN` , I am thinking my other answer might be a tiny bit faster . However this one is shorter .

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM image
GROUP BY idA
ORDER BY Doc_type DESC
```

Another:

```
SELECT IF(Doc_type LIKE 'jpg', 1, 2) sortOrder, *
FROM image
GROUP BY idA
ORDER BY sortOrder
```

or you can even move the IF statement directly into `ORDER BY` clause.

Whatever works for you best.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way of achieving it :

```
SELECT
     COALESCE( jpg_images.`Id`       ,doc_images.`Id`       ,0  ) AS Id
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`Idu`      ,doc_images.`Idu`      ,0  ) AS Idu
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`idA`      ,doc_images.`idA`      ,0  ) AS idA
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`Doc_pic`  ,doc_images.`Doc_pic`  ,'' ) AS Doc_pic
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`Doc_cont` ,doc_images.`Doc_cont` ,'' ) AS Doc_cont
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`Doc_name` ,doc_images.`Doc_name` ,'' ) AS Doc_name
    ,COALESCE( jpg_images.`Doc_type` ,doc_images.`Doc_type` ,'' ) AS Doc_type
FROM
    ( SELECT DISTINCT idA FROM image ) idA_list

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                image
            WHERE
                Doc_type = 'jpg'
            GROUP BY idA
        )
        jpg_images ON jpg_images.idA = idA_list.idA

    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        (
            SELECT
                *
            FROM
                image
            WHERE
                Doc_type = 'doc'
            GROUP BY idA
        )
        doc_images ON doc_images.idA = idA_list.idA
```

Could be expensive on large tables .

Used the below table for test :

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `image`
--

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `image` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Idu` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `idA` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Doc_pic` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Doc_cont` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `Doc_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `Doc_type` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `image`
--

INSERT INTO `image` (`Id`, `Idu`, `idA`, `Doc_pic`, `Doc_cont`, `Doc_name`, `Doc_type`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1, 'yes', 'no', 'a.jpg', 'jpg'),
(3, 1, 2, 'yes', 'no', 'c.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(4, 1, 2, 'no', 'yes', 'D_doc.jpg', 'Doc'),
(5, 1, 3, 'yes', 'no', 'e.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(6, 1, 3, 'yes', 'no', 'f.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(7, 1, 3, 'no', 'yes', 'G_doc.jpg', 'Doc'),
(8, 2, 5, 'no', 'yes', 'F_doc.jpg', 'Doc'),
(9, 3, 6, 'yes', 'no', 'h.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(10, 3, 8, 'yes', 'no', 'j.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(11, 4, 4, 'no', 'yes', 'K_doc.jpg', 'Doc'),
(12, 4, 4, 'no', 'yes', 'L_doc.jpg', 'Doc'),
(13, 4, 4, 'yes', 'no', 'm.jpg', 'Jpg'),
(14, 4, 9, 'yes', 'no', 'n.jpg', 'Jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM image WHERE Doc_name LIKE '%.jpg%'
```

This is example : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp